# Изменение набора значений списка по выбору значения в другом списке

Tags: php, javascript

Есть один select, значение которого печатаются кодом php. Нужно по выбору значения в первом списке, изменить набор значений во втором. Понимаю, что js наверное, но не знаю куда смотреть.

```
<div class="styled-select">
     <select id="regionSelect" onchange="">
     <?php
     foreach ($countries as $key => $value) 
     {
    echo "<option value='$value->id'>".$value->name."</option>";    
     }
     ?>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="styled-select">
<select id="communitySelect">
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь походу то, что Вам надо:
http://www.site-do.ru/js/js8.php

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло)